# „Parabolic estimates“: existence of limits

Tags: partial-differential-equations, parabolic-pde

Consider a reaction-diffusion equation 
$$u_t=u_{xx}+f(u)$$ 
on $(x,t)\in\mathbb{R}\times [0,\infty)$ with non-linearity $f(u)$.

Suppose, we have a continuous initial datum $u_0(x):=u(x,0)$ such that the limits $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}u_0(x)$ exist.

I have read that, assuming the solution has no blow-up, *standard parabolic estimates* imply that for the associated solution $u(x,t)$, the limits $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}u(x,t)$ exist for all times $t>0$.

To be honest, I have no idea which standard parabolic estimates are meant.

I googled a lot but did not find any estimates which give me this implication. Does anybody know what might be meant?

Answer (score 1):

Without additional assumptions this statement is false, take e.g.
$$
u_0(x)=1\\
f(u)=u^2\\
\Rightarrow u(x,t)=\frac{1}{1-t}
$$

Please share all assumptions.

Comment: Another assumption is that there is no blow-up. Sorry, I forgot to mention that.

Comment: You mean, you assume the existence of the solution for all $t>0$? If so, in what sense and function space?

Comment: Yes, and the function space is $L^\infty$ or $C^2$.